# Extrair e printar valores específicos de um xml usando Python

Tags: python, xml

Olá :)

Estou tentando capturar dados de um xml para utilizar em uma pesquisa usando python, porém meu algoritmo só está retornado os dados das ultimas tags, exemplo: O xml se encontra em http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/senador/lista/atual?uf=sp e dentro do mesmo, existem três tags contendo os dados dos parlamentares, as tags possuem o nome de "Parlamentar", ao rodar o código, o mesmo só retorna os dados do ultimo parlamentar e não os dados do 3, segue código utilizado:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import dicttoxml
from xml.etree import ElementTree as elements

URL = "http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/senador/lista/atual?uf=sp"

dados = requests.get(url=URL)
dadosx = xmltodict.parse(dados.content)
dadosxml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(dadosx)

root = elements.fromstring(dadosxml)
levels = root.findall('.//IdentificacaoParlamentar')
for level in levels:
name = level.find('NomeParlamentar').text
code = level.find('CodigoParlamentar').text
print name, code
```

Este código está me retornando apenas:

Marta Suplicy 5000

Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando?

Desde já agradeço a atenção :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os blocos de código **Python** "funcionam" de acordo com sua **indentação**, seu código está retornando apenas 1 nome pois ele passa por todo `for` e apenas `"escreve"` o ultimo item na variável nome, o seu código deveria ser:

```
import requests
import xmltodict
import dicttoxml
from xml.etree import ElementTree as elements

URL = "http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/senador/lista/atual?uf=sp"

dados = requests.get(url=URL)
dadosx = xmltodict.parse(dados.content)
dadosxml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(dadosx)

root = elements.fromstring(dadosxml)
levels = root.findall('.//IdentificacaoParlamentar')
for level in levels:
  name = level.find('NomeParlamentar').text
  code = level.find('CodigoParlamentar').text
  print(name)
  print(code)
```

**Saída:**

> Airton Sandoval 5140
>
> José Serra 90
>
> Marta Suplicy 5000

[Nesse site](https://www.pythonbay.com/blog/2017/03/09/indentacao-do-codigo-no-python/) é falado um pouco sobre o funcionamento da **indentação**

Comment: Muito Obrigado Barbetta, vou ler a referência que vc me passou ;)

Answer (score 1):

Esta faltando identação no print para que os valores iterados sejam impressos

```
for level in levels:
    name = level.find('NomeParlamentar').text
    code = level.find('CodigoParlamentar').text
    print(name, code)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Airton Sandoval 5140
José Serra 90
Marta Suplicy 5000
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Willian, era isso mesmo \o/ \o/ \o/ \o/